# Since a reference variable is an alias to another variable, how is it possible that we work with this scoped variable from another function?

Tags: c++, function, stack, pass-by-reference, heap-memory

Since a reference variable is an alias to another variable, how is it possible that we use the reference in another function. For example:

```
void func(int& a){
    a *= 4;
    return;
}

int main(){
    int n = 3;
    func(n);
    std::cout << n << std::endl; //displays 12
}
```

Here, the variable 'n' is bounded by the *main* stack frame (right?). So, how can it be used in the function *func* (because it does not exist in its scope)?

Is it the case that 'n' will be stored in the heap because it is passed by reference to another function?

Comment: You can access `n` from `func` because you provided `func` with a reference explicitly. Can you share why you think this shouldn't work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  `a` is a reference, or an alias to thing passed to the function.  Since you pass `n` to the function, `a` becomes an alias for `n`.  What about that is confusing you?

Comment: References are sometimes *similar* to aliases, but they're really more than just plain aliases. As exemplified by your code. In your example the reference variable `a` in `func` is more like a pointer, with automatic dereferencing, and in the call the compiler generates code to pass a pointer to `n` from `main`.

Comment: ```n``` goes out of scope at the end of the ```main```, so it is still "alive" when ```func``` is called

Comment: If you understand why `int main() { int n = 3; int &a = n; a *= 4; cout << n; }` prints `12` then replacing `int &a = n; a *= 4;` with `func(n);` does the exact same thing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the standard literally states that a reference IS an alias.  The fact that a reference ACTS like a pointer is an *implementation detail* of the compiler. Using an actual pointer is the most common and easiest way for a compiler to implement a reference, but that is not a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking in terms of scope, think about it in terms of memory location.
When you pass *n* in *func* as a reference, think like compiler is creating a new name *a* for the same memory location.